# Left Outer Join of two tables using two columns on each side, where one column on one side is a substring

Tags: sql, left-join, sap-ase

Hi I have found lots of threads about joining two columns in two tables but not where using a column created by a substring on one side of the join, in ASE. This is role to user assignment data and is read in from the source system with additional data that I need to subtract from the start of the `roleAssignments` field, then add the prefix `PRIV:ROLE:REPNAME:` to be able to match with what I have in the IdM database.

The SQL I have at present is:

```
select 
distinct(l.mcthismskeyvalue) as logonuid, 
l.mcothermskeyvalue, 
FROM idmv_link_ext l
left outer join
roleAssign s on l.mcthismskeyvalue = 'PRIV:ROLE:REPNAME' || ':' || substring(s.roleassignments,43,30) as roleAssignments2 
where l.mcothermskeyvalue like 'PRIV:ROLE:REPNAME:%' 
and l.mcthisocname='MX_PERSON' 
and l.mcthismskeyvalue = 'TEST_MU1';
```

The end result I am looking for is that I can see the results that are on `roleAssign` and are not on `idmv_link_ext`, then run the reverse to see results that are in `idmv_link_ext` and not in `roleAssign`. In Oracle this was possible using `MINUS` statement but the same command is not working for me in ASE. Also looked at a `where not exists` but cannot get the syntax right there either:

```
    select l.mcthismskeyvalue as logonuid, l.mcothermskeyvalue as roleAssignments 
FROM idmv_link_ext l where mcothermskeyvalue like 'PRIV:ROLE:REPNAME%' and mcthisocname='MX_PERSON' 
and l.mcthismskeyvalue = 'TEST_MU1' 
where (not exists 
(select s.refid as logonuid, 'PRIV:ROLE:REPNAME' || ':' || substring(s.roleassignments,43,30) as roleAssignments 
FROM roleAssign s
where s.refid = 'TEST_MU1'))
;
```

This is the working Oracle syntax using MINUS, for reference:

```
    select mcthismskeyvalue as logonuid, 
 * substring(mcothermskeyvalue,11,60) as roleassignments 
 * FROM idmv_link_ext where mcothermskeyvalue like 'PRIV:ROLE:REPNAME%' and mcthisocname='MX_PERSON'
minus  
 * select refid as logonuid, 'REPNAME' || ':' || substring(roleassignments,43,30) as roleAssignments 
 * FROM roleAssign
```

I have adjusted my ASE queries to remove the need for a substring on both sides in  an effort to simplify.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi. The standard SQL name for MINUS is EXCEPT & it can be calculated via NOT IN, NOT EXISTS & an idiom using LEFT JOIN ON with IS NULL. That is a faq you can easily find.

Comment: In this version of ASE, 16 sp02, EXCEPT and MINUS both give an error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword EXCEPT". NOT IN while using a substring to produce a calculated dataset in a column also has not worked for me. Perhaps I need to look into creating a view or temp table but was hoping to avoid it as it works fine in Oracle.

Comment: What exactly is your question? PS T-SQL has EXCEPT so show your attempt at using it. Also your other "has not worked". Also please read & act on [mcve].